# Two way binding Directive + Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am dynamically adding a text field in DOM (from directive link function) & want to grab entered value and push it to controller scope object, but its always giving me **undefined**, below is my code:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="fieldIcon input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-sticky-note" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    <select name="addlist[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option ng-repeat="options in optionList">{{options.label}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('myapp')
    .controller('AddContactController',[ '$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.optionList = [{label: 'NewList'}];        

        $scope.addOption = function(optionList) {
            console.log('List:', optionList); // its giving undefined
            scope.optionList.push(optionList);
        }

    }])
    .directive('optionList', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '/templates/int_optionList.html',
            controller: 'AddContactController',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                // Adding input field and on click of a button controllers addOption function should be called with the text field value
                var addListField = '<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-modal="addList" name="addList" placeholder="Add new list...">'+
                +'<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="addOption()">';

                addListField = $compile(addListField)(scope);
                $(element).find('.multiselect-container').prepend(addListField);
            }
        }
    }]);
</script>
```

Now here in addOption function I am getting optionList value as undefined.

Comment: `addOption` expects an argument but you don't pass one.

Comment: Yeah sorry for that, in actual code I have while posting here I missed it, so even with that argument, still getting undefined.
Note: Edited my post

Comment: You aren't actually using the `option-list` directive anywhere in your template code, so is the directive's link function even firing?

Comment: Maybe i don't understand the question, but what is ng-modal ? Did you mean ng-model instead ?

Comment: @Silvinus nice catch man... I am soooo stupid, spent couple of hours to make it work... :(, please post this as an answer so I can accept it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is human :).
Replace ng-modal by ng-model in your directive

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS expects models to be in object form, setting ng-modal="addList" to ng-modal="data.addList" might help.

Comment: That is not true. It is a good practice (as also using ControllerAs that will "force" this), but not something angular expects.